# OpenStack client image save overflows RAM

Tags: openstack

I got an image that is 128GB. Tried to download it with `openstack image save --file ...` but it seems that client puts whole the file into the ram first. Of course it overflows it and fails. Why is that? How do I download image much bigger than available ram on the client machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [glance client](https://docs.openstack.org/python-glanceclient/latest/cli/details.html#glance-image-download), or you [just use the API](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/image/v2/index.html?expanded=download-binary-image-data-detail#download-binary-image-data). The latter requires an authentication token in the *x-auth-token* HTTP header, which you can acquire with the `openstack token issue` command.

The openstack client might have memory issues, but I doubt that the entire image is copied to memory. I can't remember having seen this.

Comment: glance worked perfectly, thank you